# Authenticate user after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, encryption

I have two separate servers (s1 and s2) with two separate web applications running. The user is authenticated on s1 and by clicking a link gets redirected to s2. Is it possible to authenticate the user on s2 without having the user to enter his/hers credentials again?

My first thought was to encrypt a password with a secret key known by both servers and pass the encrypted string with the request. Is that enough? Is there a smarter way to go about doing this?

```
  _________                             __________
  |   s1  |  GET (with encrypted pw)?   |   s2   |
  |       |  ----------------------->   |        |
  |_______|                             |________|
Authenticated                   Need to be authenticated
```

Thanks.

Comment: That just fine. You can make it a bit reusable by creating a web service like interface in s2.

Comment: Is it possible to get the secret key if you know the password (let's say it's a md5 hash)?

Comment: md5 is quite weak hashing algorithm. It can be cracked using brute force. use SHA256/SHA512 instead. Also make sure that you append a secret key to the password, such as "MyPassword" + "ASuperSecretKey" and you'll be secured

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass credentials in the querystring or use cross domain cookies.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm

http://anantgarg.com/2010/02/18/cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/